# How to filter java stream and return only items starting with a list of provided substrings

Tags: spring-boot, java-stream

I have a list of authorities returned when user authenticates in Spring Boot app.

For example, I get list of granted authorities like:

```
user_1_authority, 
user_2_authority,  
group_1_authority,  
group_2_authority,  
test_1_authority, 
test_2_authority, 
driver_x_authority,
...
```

I would like to filter these authorities so that I get back only authorities starting with "user_" OR "group_".

I wonder how can I use Java streams to return a new list of filtered authorities to have something like:

```java
  List<String> authoritiesStartingWithList = Arrays.asList("user_", "group_");

  public Collection<GrantedAuthorities> filterAuthorities(Authentication authentication, List<String> authoritiesStartingWithList) {
    return authentication.getAuthorities().stream().contains(authoritiesStartingWithList);
  }
```

this would return a list containing only:

```
user_1_authority, 
user_2_authority,  
group_1_authority,  
group_2_authority,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following solution:

```java
List<String> authoritiesStartingWithList = Arrays.asList("user_", "group_");

public Collection<GrantedAuthority> filterAuthorities(Authentication authentication, List<String> authoritiesStartingWithList) {
  return authentication.getAuthorities().stream().filter(this::startsWithOneOfPredefinedValues).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private boolean startsWithOneOfPredefinedValues(GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority) {
  return authoritiesStartingWithList.stream().anyMatch(i->grantedAuthority.getAuthority().startsWith(i));
}
```

The filtering method is used to iterate through the list of prefixes to check if there are any matches, if no matches are found, authority is filtered out from the stream.

Comment: I am having problems understanding steams.... any reason why you use ```authoritiesStartingWithList``` list as a global variable?  Why not pass it into the ```startsWithOneOfPredefinedValues()``` method where it is actually used?  Would that change how filter is used in ```filterAuthorities()``` where you pass the method to the filter? 
 Thanks again

Comment: The reason is it is defined as a global variable in the question. In case you want to pass the list as a parameter, the filter part should be defined as: `.filter(i -> startsWithOneOfPredefinedValues( i, authoritiesStartingWithList))`. Probably the double colon operator is confusing you, check [this](https://www.java67.com/2018/06/what-is-double-colon-operator-in-java-8.html).